# VB C# o Api Windows Formulario sin barra de menu pero redimensionable

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, windows-forms, winapi

Mi pregunta es:
Ya teniendo un formulario, ¿Como puedo quitarle la barra de titulo sin perder la capacidad de redimensionar?
Tengo el siguiente código que realiza algo similar pero aun sigue mostrándose una pequeña porción de la barra de titulo

```html
Dim hwnd As IntPtr = Me.Handle
Dim style As Integer = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
style = style And Not WS_CAPTION 'Probando opciones
 style = 0
'style = WS_POPUP Or WS_BORDER Or WS_THICKFRAME 'Esto es lo qu ele da ese efecto a la ventana de borde arriba
style = WS_POPUP Or WS_EX_APPWINDOW
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style)
SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME Or SWP_NOACTIVATE Or SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOZORDER)
```

El mejor ejemplo de lo que necesito es el propio visual studio o Google Chrome, simular esto a través de areas dentro de mi form como lo hace Discord no quisiera.
Necesito saber como resolver eso de manera que luego pueda exportar la dll para usar en proyecto vb.net o c# en el caso de que la resolución no este dentro de las tecnologías de net framework o estilos de ventanas de windows y así luego ponerle mis controles para continuar el programa
De antemano Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hay tres etiquetas de lenguaje en tu pregunta ¿De qué lenguaje quieres realmente hablar?

Comment: no me importa le lenguaje solo el resultado, el objetivo es que la ventana sea redimensionable usando la propia caracteristica de windows

Comment: ¿Te viene bien entonces una respuesta en [MarioLANG](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MarioLANG)?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Si MarioLANG pudiera ser incluido en un proyecto WinForms le serviría (no tengo idea de que si es posible), si sé que es posible integrar dll desarrolladas en C#, VB.net y C++ en un winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Quitar los bordes puedes hacer

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Luego para permitir redimensionar debes usar el método `WndProc`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
            
        base.WndProc(ref m);
            
        if (m.Msg != 132 || m.Result != 1) return;
            
        Point screenPoint = new(m.LParam.ToInt32());
        Point clientPoint = PointToClient(screenPoint);
        const int BORDE_SIZE = 10;

        Func<int, int, int, IntPtr> GetId = (int A, int B, int C) => {
            if (clientPoint.X <= BORDE_SIZE) return A;
            else if (clientPoint.X < (Size.Width - BORDE_SIZE)) return B;
            else return C;
        };

        if (clientPoint.Y <= BORDE_SIZE)
            m.Result = GetId(13, 12, 14);
        else if (clientPoint.Y <= (Size.Height - BORDE_SIZE))
            m.Result = GetId(10, 2, 11);
        else
            m.Result = GetId(16, 15, 17);
    }

}
```

Este código lo que hace es establecer un borde "imaginario" (`BORDE_SIZE`) y cuando el mouse está arriba del borde se activa el redimensionamiento, para ello se debe detectar y calcular la posición del mouse para determinar en que borde se encuentra (arriba, abajo, izquierda, derecha)

Los números con que se setea a `m.result`, corresponden a los códigos [WM_NCHITTEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest)

Comment: Esto me ha funcionado de maravilla, gracias